# Does a UVC transparent polymer exist or can it be made?

Tags: polymers

Does a UVC transparent polymer exist or can it be made?

I am trying to find a polymer that can transmit UVC light. Most materials absorb this 265 265 nm range. for example quartz passes UVC but glass does not. I have tried a UVC transparent silicone but the losses are to great.

Comment: What are other requirements, aside of UVC transparency? Generally, provide to any question enough of relevant info to avoid clarification ping-pong. What do you mean be "265 265 nm range" ?